# How do I implement a filter in PowerShell?

Tags: function, powershell, filter

I'm trying to figure out a way to incorporate a filter into a custom function and I haven't been able to get it working:

```
Function Test-Me{
    Param
    (
      $Filter = "Number -like ""Three"""
    )

    $Obj = New-Object PSObject -Properties &{
                                             Number = "One","Two","Three"
                                            }

    If($Filter){
     $Obj | Where-Object $Filter
    }else{
     $Obj
    }
}
```

I've tried various means, but they all fail:

```
$Filter = 'Where-Object{$_' + $Filter + '}'
$Obj | & $Filter
```

.

```
$Filter = "Number -like ""One"""
$Obj | Where & $Filter
```

How do you incorporate `Filter` support into custom functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the parameter type to `ScriptBlock`:

```
Function Test-Me {
  Param(
    [ScriptBlock]$Filter = {$_.Number -like 'Three'}
  )

  $Obj = 'One','Two','Three' | % {[PSCustomObject]@{Number = $_}}
  $Obj | Where-Object $Filter
}
```

and define the filters as actual scriptblocks:

```
PS C:\> Function Test-Me {
>>   Param([ScriptBlock]$Filter = {$_.Number -like 'Three'})
>>   $Obj = 'One','Two','Three' | % {[PSCustomObject]@{Number = $_}}
>>   $Obj | Where-Object $Filter
>> }
>>
PS C:\> Test-Me

Number
------
Three

PS C:\> $sb = { $_.Number -like 't*' }
PS C:\> Test-Me $sb

Number
------
Two
Three

PS C:\> Test-Me {$_.Number -like '*e'}

Number
------
One
Three
```

If your function must accept string input for some reason you could [create scriptblocks](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/05/21/powertip-create-a-powershell-script-block-on-the-fly.aspx) from the strings, as [@Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31812706/1630171) suggested:

```
Function Test-Me {
  Param(
    [string]$Filter = '$_.Number -like "Three"'
  )

  $fltr = [ScriptBlock]::Create($Filter)

  $Obj = 'One','Two','Three' | % {[PSCustomObject]@{Number = $_}}
  $Obj | Where-Object $fltr
}
```

Comment: You don't actually have to include the `$_` with your filter.  But this is the closest to a real answer so I'll accept yours.

Comment: @Colyn1337 The simplified syntax only works for simple expressions and only in PowerShell v3 and newer. If for instance you want to combine 2 or more conditions with logical operators (`$_.Number -like 't*' -or $_.Number -like '*e'`) you must use `$_`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just pass a string and expect it to be expanded as the cmdlet's parameters: PowerShell's parsing is more sophisticated than that.

But you should be able to convert a string into a script block (for example, [see here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/05/21/powertip-create-a-powershell-script-block-on-the-fly.aspx)). Then pass the script block to `Where-Object`'s `-FilterScript` parameter.